# Stop text from breaking lines

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a problem with my site. For some reason my text is breaking lines.

For example I have the word `Hip Hop` but it's showing up as

`Hip
Hop`

here is the html

```
 <div class="medium-2 column first-post-category">
 <h1 class="category-first"><?php $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0]; echo '<a href="' . get_bloginfo('url') . '/category/' . $cat->category_nicename . '">'; echo $cat->cat_name; echo  '</a>'; ?></h1>
 </div>
```

and here is the css

```
.first-post-category{
position:absolute;
top:6%;
left:1%;
}

.category-first{
background:#0076c1;
font-family:'Khula', sans-serif;
font-size:30px;
color:#fff;
padding:6px;
}
```

here a photo example.

[Photo One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlpSQ.png)

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML and not the PHP

Comment: Try and apply 'white-space: nowrap;' in the CSS

Comment: That worked @NeilKennedy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with your current code  it renders fine, but whenever you **don't** want break text into another line use [`white-space: nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

> **nowrap**
>
> Collapses whitespace as for normal, but suppresses line breaks (text wrapping) within text.

```css
.first-post-category {
  position: absolute;
  top: 6%;
  left: 1%;
}
.category-first {
  background: #0076c1;
  font-family: 'Khula', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px;
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

```html
<div class="medium-2 column first-post-category">
  <h1 class="category-first">Hip Hop</h1>
</div>
```